# Lombok @EqualsAndHashcode

Tags: java, equals, lombok, hashcode

I am implementing Lombok @EqualsAndHashcode annotation. I need to control order of parameters included in hashCode() generation. For example Lombok generates this:

```
public int hashCode() {
    final int prime = 59;
    int result = 1;

    result = prime * result + parOne; //First
    result = prime * result + parTwo; //Second

    return result;
}
```

But I need it to be like:

```
public int hashCode() {
    final int prime = 59;
    int result = 1;

    result = prime * result + parTwo; //Second
    result = prime * result + parOne; //First

    return result;
}
```

Two methods above generate different hash codes.
My question is: can I control order of parameters using Lombok?

I have already tried: `@EqualsAndHashCode(doNotUseGetters = true, of = {"parTwo", "parOne"})` but it is not working.

Comment: When you want "partTwo" to be actually "partOne", then why don't you setup your class to be that way, i.e. reordering the properties? And when switching the order yields different hashcodes, when it sounds like generating the hashcode or accessing "partTwo" and "partOne" has side effects and this shouldn't happening.

Comment: Why is this even an issue? The order is the same across all instances of the class, so the generation of the hashCode is consistent.

Comment: This class is an entity class, I cannot change order of fields. The generated hash could be saved somewhere and then reused, the order was like this without Lombok implementation.

Comment: You should never rely on the consistency of a `hashCode()`, as its contract explicitly states that it "need not remain consistent from one execution of an application to another execution of the same application". Persisting and re-using a such a hash is a bad idea.